# RPLY - Unexpected token parsing source code with multiple lines of code

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, cobol, ply

I'm experimenting with the RPLY library, which by the way looks awesome. However, my parser works fine if my source code has just one line in it. If I add another line of code the parser throws an exception. Anyone else seen this. My parser is pretty basic as the moment, and if I parse each line individually then I have no problem.

My source code looks like this:

```
MULTIPLY 10 BY 20 GIVING PRICE.
* This is a comment.
```

as I say, parsing each line separately is no problem.

Any help/pointers greatly received!!!

Comment: You might want to add a tag to your question stating which programming language you're using to parse. For someone unfamiliar with the library you mention, the language is just not obvious.

Comment: What token was unexpected? Are you using fixed or free format for the COBOL code?

Comment: The unexpected token is on the next line. So, given the example above, the unexpected token in a comment ("*"). My parser production looks like:`'program : MULTIPLY expression BY expression GIVING expression PERIOD` The lexer produces: `Token('MULTIPLY', 'MULTIPLY')
Token('INTEGER', '10')
Token('BY', 'BY')
Token('INTEGER', '20')
Token('GIVING', 'GIVING')
Token('IDENTIFIER', 'PRICE')
Token('PERIOD', '.')
Token('COMMENT', '* This is a comment.')`

Comment: free format, forgot to mention :-)

Comment: In free format, a comment begins with `*>`. This is done to prevent an ambiguity because, in free format, `*` is multiply in an arithmetic instruction. For example, `compute price = 10 * 20`. I suspected that the `*` might be the problem, but with `Token('COMMENT', ...` as a production, I am not so sure.

Comment: What's the start symbol? Does it accept one statement or multiple statements?

Comment: What do you mean by start symbol? Are you thinking that I don’t have a production for a list of statements??

Comment: I wonder whether `COMMENT` is the "unexpected token". That can be tested by placing parts of the `MULTIPLY` statement on separate lines.

Comment: No matter what the next line is, it will cause an error. I've used Comment in the code example, but if I replace that with another MULTIPLY statement, that will be the next error. It seems to be relating to having more than one lines of code in the source file. I must have something wrong with my productions as not processing multiple lines of code,

Comment: If `program` is the start symbol, then any production after the `MULTIPLY` statement will be an "unexpected token". You could also place the comment on the same line as the `multiply` statement to see if it fails. Beyond that I think you will need to post some code for others to examine.